# Linking zmq to a c++ program in ndnsim

Tags: zeromq, waf, ndnsim

How can I link zmq to a CPP program in ndnsim?

I'm encountering challenges while attempting to integrate ZeroMQ with ndnSIM 2.9. My focus is on modifying the wscript file in the ns-3 folder. I've tried to modify but doesn't work.

I've searched through the ndnSIM and ZeroMQ documentation without success. Could someone provide guidance on the correct modifications to the wscript file for successful integration?